# Knockout.js select data-bind value is not read but is written

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: warehouseOrders().StoreOrders -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b data-bind="text: Product"></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b data-bind="text: Store"></b>`enter code here`
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b data-bind="text: Quantity"></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select data-bind=" value: OrderStatusId , options: $parent.orderStatuses(), optionsText: 'Status', optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
                            <b data-bind="text: OrderStatusId"></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--/ko-->
```

So StoreOrders contains all properties : Product, Store,Quantity,OrderStatusId.

The specific problem: select options: `$parent.orderStatuses()` contains a list of orderstatuses(Id,Status). I set text and value properties for the select. All works fine, when selecting an option it is written into OrderStatusId property of the object, but initially, OrderStatusId contains a value, which knockout should read and set in the select. So when i open up select should be on that value.

Here are the models:

Main class:

```
public class WarehouseDTO
    {
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public List<StoreOrderDTO> StoreOrders { get; set; }
        public List<StoreWarehouseDTO> StoreWarehouses { get; set; }
        public List<WarehouseProductDTO> WarehouseProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

and the StoreOrderDTO

```
public class StoreOrderDTO
    {
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Store { get; set; }
        public string Warehouse { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public System.Guid OrderStatusId { get; set; }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
self.warehouseOrdersRequest = function (item) {
        ajaxHelper('/api/OrderStatus', 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.orderStatuses(data);
        });
        self.warehouseOrders(item);
    }
```

Here item represents 1 object of the type `WarehouseDTO`, and `OrderStatuses` is given an array of objects {Id,Status}

full code of the table

```
<!--ko if : warehouseOrders()-->
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title"><b data-bind="text: warehouseOrders().Name"></b> - Orders</h2>
                </div>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Product")
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Store")
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Quantity")
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Order Status")
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                    <!-- ko foreach: warehouseOrders().StoreOrders -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b data-bind="text: Product"></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b data-bind="text: Store"></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b data-bind="text: Quantity"></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select data-bind=" value: OrderStatusId , options: $parent.orderStatuses(), optionsText: 'Status', optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
                            <b data-bind="text: OrderStatusId"></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--/ko-->
                </table> 
            </div>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: closeWarehouseOrders" class="btn btn-defaul">Cancel</a>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: saveWarehouseOrders" class="btn btn-defaul">Save</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ko-->
```

I noticed something, that after I select an item, and its written into OrderStatusId the `<b data-bind="text: OrderStatusId"></b>` is displayed(it didn`t before), and yes, im sure there is a value in it.

Comment: And interestingly enough, that <b data-bind="text: OrderStatusId"></b> after select is not working either...

Comment: Can you show us your viewmodels? Are you sure your ids are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `orderStatuses` are loaded async, while the current state isn't, knockout cannot correctly initialize the `<select>` data-binds here:

```
<select data-bind=" value: OrderStatusId , options: $parent.orderStatuses(), optionsText: 'Status', optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
```

At the time of binding, `$parent.orderStatuses()` is an empty array. `OrderStatusId` is a string. There are no options to look for the `option.Id == value` that is used to set the initial value.

When updating the observable options array, knockout *apparently* does not retry to match the currently selected value to one of the new options. (citation needed, I tried to look up the source to back this up but couldn't find it quickly enough...)

One way you could fix this is by preventing initialization of the `<select>` when the `statuses` haven't yet loaded:

```
<!-- ko if: orderStatuses().length -->
<select data-bind="options: orderStatuses"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

You can see this fix in the example below. When you remove the virtual `if` binding element, you'll see the initial status is no longer set. Also, when you swap the order of `setItem` and `setStatuses`, you'll notice you no longer need the extra if-bind.

```js
var vm = {
  item: ko.observable(),
  statuses: ko.observableArray([])
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);

var setItem = function() {

  vm.item({
    orders: ko.observableArray([{
        text: "Item 1",
        status: ko.observable(0)
      }, {
        text: "Item 2",
        status: ko.observable(1)
      }

    ])
  });
}

var setStatuses = function() {
  vm.statuses([{
    label: "Status 0",
    id: 0
  }, {
    label: "Status 1",
    id: 1
  }]);
}

setItem();
setStatuses();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko if: item -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: item().orders">
  <li>
    <div data-bind="text: text"></div>
    
    <!-- ko if: $parent.statuses().length -->
    <select data-bind="options: $parent.statuses, value: status, optionsText: 'label', optionsValue: 'id'"></select>
    <strong data-bind="text: 'status: ' + status()"></strong>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Looked into it quite a bit but couldn`t find a thing. Thank you sir.